# Create List from Microsoft Access 2007 database in WSS 3.0 with sync capability

Tags: database, sync

Is there an easier way to -

- Create a List from a database (.mdb) file on WSS 3.0
- Once the list is up, I want to sync it with database. i.e. Any changes I make to the database  file offline should be able sync with the List which is created.

I have tried it but sometimes it does not sync. I am sure I am missing some steps. 
Please help me out!

Thanks!
-saumil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can provision a list from within Access 2007, however you can Link To or Populate an existing SharePoint list with an Access table from within Access 2007. Ensure you select "Link" to rather than Import the data.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a link which explains the whole process?

Comment: Sure, this is what I used last time:
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=68